# Sharing firebase auth state with web worker for firestore queries that require authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, service-worker, web-worker

We are testing using web workers to handle certain firestore queries in the background. The process is fairly well documented, until we are need to query collections that require user authentication as determined by our firestore security rules. Those collections respond with a 'Missing or Insufficient Permissions' error even though the user is logged in, since the user's auth state is not available in the worker.

Is it possible to share the user's auth state with the worker?

```js
// my-firestore-worker.worker.ts
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

import {
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  getFirestore,
  query,
} from "@firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const app = initializeApp({
 /* none of your business */
});

const firestore = getFirestore(app);

addEventListener("message", async (ev) => {
  // This works because the document is allowed for unauthenticated users in our firestore security rules
  const appConfig = await getDoc(
    doc(
      firestore,
      `/app/public-config`
    )
  );

  // This gives 'Missing or insufficient permissions' error because of firestore security rules
  const projectFilesSnapshot = await getDocs(
    query(collection(firestore, `/projects/my-project/tasks`))
  );
});
```

Other Observations:

- The firebase v9 JavaScript SDK is built using `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, which seems good since `XMLHttpRequest` is not supported in workers
- Firebase auth has a `reauthenticateWithCredential` method, but it would require storing the password on the client so that is not a good option.

Prior art:

https://davidea.st/articles/firebase-bundle-size/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/service-worker-sessions

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: Great question... did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Followed the same way and eventually found that firestore pickup authorization inside a worker when you just initialize `firebase/auth`.

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, limit } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp({
 // settings
});


getAuth(app); // <-- this makes everything works

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

addEventListener('message', async ({ data }) => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "campaigns"), limit(100));

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  const rows = [];

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    rows.push(doc.data());
  })

  const response = `worker response to ${rows.length}`;

  postMessage(response);
});
```

Comment: Importing getAuth() causes the build to fail because auth accesses the DOM, which is not accessible in a web worker. You might get some "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Window'" or "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'" errors

Comment: Yes, i have also seen that, but this is just about typescript complaining about typings of functions which you are not using. As a workaround i just enabled "skipLibCheck" in tsconfig.  getAuth() actually don't use any DOM methods while initialization.